# Is there a more efficient way of writing the coalesce function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, null, coalesce

After looking through some code, the following function was found:

```
def coalesce(*args, null=None):
    return next((obj for obj in args if obj is not null and obj != null), null)
```

Is there a more efficient way to have this operation run or a more Pythonic way of thinking about the problem?

The first alternative tried was the following:

```
def coalesce(*args):
    return next(filter(None, args), None)
```

Here is the second alternative that was tried:

```
def coalesce(*args, null=None):
    return next(itertools.filterfalse(functools.partial(operator.eq, null), args), null)
```

This is a third alternative that came to mind:

```
def coalesce(*args):
    return next((obj for obj in args if obj is not None), None)
```

A fourth alternative was written in the hopes that code written in C would be faster:

```
def coalesce(*args):
    return next(itertools.filterfalse(functools.partial(operator.is_, None), args), None)
```

Using `timeit`, the timing results for the three different functions were:

- 0.7040689999994356
- 0.3396129999891855
- 0.8870604000112507
- 0.5313313000078779
- 0.8086609000019962

This would seem to indicate that the second function is preferable, but that does not answer the question of which is most Pythonic.

Comment: What was your test case?

Comment: is there a case where null is not None? if not, remove it from the question

Comment: Your alternatives filter out all false values, not just ones identical or equal to `null`.

Comment: `return next(filter(None, args), None)` sounds very good if you assume that null == None. And without surprise it's the fastest. But it filters out falsy objects as chepner noted

Comment: "Simple is better than complex". Number 2. Built-ins, no extra modules, no loop, faster. What's the issue?

Comment: also `if obj is not null and obj != null` is redundant if null == None. Just use `if obj is not None`

Comment: @chepner The test case is taking a argument with a default value of `None` (meaning not provided) and replacing it with a true default value such that callers can also use `None` as their own default value without having to copy the true default value as the default value of each and every caller that also wants to default the argument.

Comment: I mean, what arguments are you passing to `coalesce`? `coalesce()`, for example, wouldn't take *any* time to run, let alone vary depending on the implementation.

Comment: @chepner While testing the function with `timeit`, the values passed in were `(None, None, 1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered

```
def coalesce4(*args):
    for x in args:
        if x is not None:
            return x
```

which is significantly faster than the three functions shown in your question:

```
In [2]: import tmp

In [3]: %timeit tmp.coalesce1(None, None, 1)
782 ns ± 1.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: %timeit tmp.coalesce2(None, None, 1)
413 ns ± 8.36 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit tmp.coalesce3(None, None, 1)
678 ns ± 0.782 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit tmp.coalesce4(None, None, 1)
280 ns ± 0.218 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

---

In Python 3.8, you'll have the option of

```
def coalesce5(*args):
    if any(rv := x for x in args if x is not None):
         return rv
```

which is effectively the same as your third option, and the running time of a similar function shows it to be about the same speed (~680 ns).

Comment: Thanks for your implementation! I am surprised that it runs in about 67% of the time as the first listed alternative. Do you have any idea why your code is faster? I was expecting code written in C to be faster than the code in Python.

Comment: The other solutions all require at least one function lookup and call. This function uses Python syntax, but the iterator and the comparison are both effectively implemented in C as well, given everything uses built-in types.

Comment: You'll get much different results with a larger set of arguments, though. Using `*[None, None, ..., 1]` (500 elements), `coalesce4` is only about 8% faster than `coalesce1` or `coalesce3`, while `coalesce2` is still about 2x faster than 1 or 3.